# AWS Quicksight Scheduling Report Delivery

Tags: amazon-web-services, business-intelligence, amazon-quicksight

Does AWS Quicksight have method of sending reports everyday to a user by email automatically? We want users ability to subscribe to reports. This way, everyone does not have to login to Quicksight web portal, but see the reports in email inbox. We require ability to schedule reports, eg one report comes everyday at 10 am, other one comes once a week at 3 pm. Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, As of 06/27/2018 AWS QuickSight has no such way to export Report/Schedule Report and send automated email.

However you can schedule data refresh as mentioned in 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/refreshing-imported-data.html#schedule-data-refresh